# Angular - Read Every Response Recieved from API

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, angularjs-directive

I want to show a flash message in my angular and PHP(API) App.

I am wondering if I can scan every response received from API and if
the server returning a JSON array with column as 'flash' then It should automatically read and show it as flash message.

For example, if response is `'flash' => 'username or password invalid'` then it should show flash as `username or password invalid` automatically without telling the service to show it

Comment: I have created one service and one function inside it and then i am manually writing service.show(msg); after the success and error response.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor and watch every HTTP call through angular's $http service by implementing an interceptor. You can review the documentation [**here**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors).

To peek into each response received you will want to implement `response` and `responseError`